How to transfer dataframe `raw_df` to `list` row by row?
How to transfer data frame raw_df  to list row by row? Desired output: wished_list
 raw_df <- data.frame(cat=c('a','b','c'),value=c('high','mid','low'))
 wished_list <- list(a='high',b='mid',c='low')


An alternative to a list would be a character vector with named elements.

One way to solve your probem:
split(raw_df$value, raw_df$cat)

$a
[1] "high"

$b
[1] "mid"

$c
[1] "low"


One option would be:
as.list(setNames(raw_df$value, raw_df$cat))

$a
[1] "high"

$b
[1] "mid"

$c
[1] "low"


Simplifying to character (vector) might be another option:
with(raw_df, structure(value, names=cat))
#>      a      b      c 
#> "high"  "mid"  "low"

## with class #> [1] "character"

If list format is no strict requirement.

List format with: with(raw_df, structure(as.list(value), names=cat))

@s_baldur Sure. I wonder if list format is really needed considering the structure of raw_df.

Or you can use tibble::deframe
> as.list(tibble::deframe(raw_df))
$a
[1] "high"

$b
[1] "mid"

$c
[1] "low"


Using Map():
with(raw_df, Map(\(x,y) y, cat, value))
# $a
# [1] "high"
# 
# $b
# [1] "mid"
# 
# $c
# [1] "low"

